# Pulse effect CSS around button not working

Tags: css, animation, button, pulse

I am trying to create a pulse effect around this button. 
Unfortunately its not working... and I can't find the error.

```css
#pulse {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}

#show {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(232, 76, 61, 0.7);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: url('bilder/showleftside.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  -ms-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
  animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pulse">
  <button id="show" type="button" onclick=""></button>
</div>
```

Comment: are the `@keyframes` for the animation `pulse` defined anywhere? Perhaps you forgot to add those?

Comment: Where and how are keyframes defined?

Comment: https://codepen.io/olam/pen/zcqea

Comment: thank you very much :)! works perfectly fine

Comment: try this codepen https://codepen.io/jaredringold/pen/zvwWyb?editors=0110

Answer (score 1):

You defined a animation with name `pulse`. What this pulse animation is supposed to do is missing in your code. Add **keyframes** to define your animation.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

```css
#pulse {
    width: 50px; 
    height: 100%; 
}



#show { 
    float: left; 
    margin: 20px;

    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    height: 40px; 
    width: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(232, 76, 61, 0.7);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;

    background-image: url('bilder/showleftside.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    -webkit-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
    -moz-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
    -ms-animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
    animation: pulse 1.25s infinite cubic-bezier(0.66, 0, 0, 1);
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pulse">
    <button id="show" type="button">X</button>
 </div>
```